# 80s (or earlier) sci fi book, humanoids bossed around by aliens

Tags: story-identification, books

There is very little I remember about this book, I read it maybe thirty years ago.

I think there was a human sphere of space surrounded by a more advanced alien race, slowly over many years the aliens were encroaching into the human sphere and taking over star systems and basically enslaving the people.

I can't remember (and I've thought hard for some days) many more plot details, except for one scene that I think must have horrified me when I first read it.

The aliens take a human girl into their interrogation centre. I think they were looking for clues to trace a rebel. She plays the "do you know who I am?" card and tells them her father is high up on the liaison council and has a lot of power and influence. They march her down to look into a cell.

The aliens have, over generations, selectively bred a human guard type, massively oversized and muscled but with tiny heads and brains. Three of these guards have her 'important' father pinned down in the cell and are taking turns anally raping him. This makes her realise how very little regard they have for humanity.

Comment: Yikes. I'm assuming Hallmark aren't planning to film this one

Comment: @Jenayah - Ah, ok. I thought there might be deleted comments.

Comment: Can I just say that, despite the description above, it's actually a very good book. With two even better sequels.

Comment: see also https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/235404/in-which-book-did-alien-protagonists-absorb-and-mutate-humans-turning-their-fle (about the second book in the series)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It sounds like [Starhammer](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1915108.Starhammer) by [Christopher Rowley](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christopher_Rowley).

It has been a while since I've read it, but the micro-cephalic guards with rape as a punishment were a recurring idea in the book.

As far as I remember, the girl was a debutante saved by the main character from a *'thrill kill cult'* (mass killings for fun). The aliens were trying to track down the main character and reckoned she could lead them to him or act as bait.

Comment: I'm annoyed at myself now, I actually own Starhammer as an ebook ... however it's been in my TBR file (hundreds of sci fi books) for several years and I keep intending to read it. If I'd even started it I would have recognised the lost story!